# Pickle in Python, incorrect received data

Tags: python, server, client, pickle

I am creating simple server client architecture using pickle. When I receive data and print it, first number disaapear, why? how can I avoid this?
for example: ({2,2,4}, {3,4}) - > ({2,4}, {3,4})

server code:
    import pickle
    import socket

```
TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()


print ("conn info: ", conn)
objrcv = pickle.loads(conn.recv(10024))
print("conn recv: ", objrcv)
print("conn from: ", addr)
print(objrcv)
```

client code

```
import socket
import pickle

name = 'name'
TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

data = pickle.dumps(name)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
# #s.send(data) #powitalne info, dane gracza

def wyslij_dane(my_array): #sending data
    data = pickle.dumps(my_array)
    if data[0] != 0:  # pierwszy argument odpowiedzialny za poddanie sie
        print('before send')
        s.send(data)
        print('after send') #just to control
        #data_recv = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        #print("received data:", data_recv)


def rozlacz():#disconnecting
    s.close()

wyslij_dane(({2,2,4}, {3,4}))
wyslij_dane({2,2,433})
wyslij_dane(0)
rozlacz()
```

server output:

```
conn info:  ...
conn recv:  ({2, 4}, {3, 4})
conn from:  ('127.0.0.1', 51876)
({2, 4}, {3, 4})
```

And another question is: What can I do to handle all sending data (all call wyslij_dane() funcions)?

Comment: `{2,2,4}` is a set and sets have unique elements. Python will interpret `{2,2,4}` to be the set `{2,4}`. This has nothing to do with pickling.

Comment: hah, stupid oversight. thanks, could you explain me what can I do to handle all sending data (all call wyslij_dane() funcions)?

Answer (score 1):

"{}" means you are using a set. In a set every item exists only once. Instead you can use a list with these -> "[]" or a tupel -> "()"
So

```
wyslij_dane(({2,2,4}, {3,4}))
```

becomes

```
wyslij_dane(([2,2,4], [3,4]))
```

and so on.